# IE8 Strange additional <li> items?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with a page in IE8 (works fine in IE6/7).  It seems to be effectively adding a new li item at the top of the list which isn't in the markup.

Can anyone suggest what could be causing this?  I have placed some code in a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p6QxV/2/

It works with Compatibility View enabled but I don't believe this be set within the page?

I can set the meta tag but that doesn't load the  CSS file

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I would like to understand what causes the problem and if I can fix it in my code/css without resorting to IE hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your self closing `<a>` tags into seperate opening and closing tags appears to fix your problem. It probably stems from the fact that `<a>` tags shouldn't self close and thus IE throws a rendering fit.

http://jsfiddle.net/p6QxV/4/